# How can I solve stiff equations by method of line (MOL)?

Tags: matlab, pde, ode, stiffness, method-of-lines

I want to solve 7 coupled equations.I use method of line(MOL) and discrete the equation in Length and radius and convert them to a system of ODEs in time.and use ode15s to solve them in MATLAB. But an error occur:

Warning: Failure at t=5.422028e-006. Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (1.355253e-020) at time t.

It means that equations are too stiff. How can i solve them? Is there another method?
The equations are true.I am sure.

Comment: Definitely make sure you don't have any programming errors in your equations.

Comment: @ choward How can i do that?its the first time i use MOL.CAN you guide me what error will occur?

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is clean up your code for the MOL part and paste it on here so we can check it out

Comment: @ choward i added code in main question.Thanks alot.

Comment: @fatemeh: re: posting code, I'd say a better practice is to break your code up into small testable units for debugging so that you can diagnose bugs and fix them quickly. Diagnosing is the hard, time-consuming part, and while posting your code does provide SciComp users with some of the information needed to investigate the issues you're having, it requires a lot of work to figure out the root of the actual problem. If you can identify the numerical issue yourself, and make that the core of your question, you are more likely to receive more actionable responses. (BillGreene's is good.)

Comment: @Geoff  I did what Bill Greens said. and i could solve the problem. then i deleted my code that added here. I will do what you said in my futures questions.thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ode15s is designed to handle stiff systems of ODEs so I doubt if the problem
you are encountering is that your "equations are too stiff"

It is more likely that your spatial discretization has an error for some
reason or your have some other MATLAB programming error. I suggest the following
approach to debug this: Set the final integration time for ode15s to be
something smaller than that when the failure occurs: say 5.2e-6 (I am assuming
the starting time is zero). Make sure you have enough output times in that
interval so you can produce reasonable plots of your dependent variables
at key points in your spatial mesh as a function of time.

My guess is if you look at these plots you will see that one or more
of your dependent variables is going to infinity or -infinity as you
approach the final time. That should give you a clue as to which equation(s)
are causing problems for ode15s.

Comment: .i doubt if discretization is true or not.can i send my program here?or can you guid me?

Comment: i added my code to main question